# Conditional loop issue in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

I have a shell script with if and elif logic. I am trying to check keyword match with grep command.Whatever keywords I am passing the script is executing last block only.here is my script.

```
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log | \
while read LINE
do
if [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c "select .*" ` -gt 0 ]
then
  AuditTypeID=15
  QueryResult=$(grep -oEi 'SELECT .*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)
elif [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c "CREATE" ` -gt 0 ]
then
  AuditTypeID=13
  QueryResult="$(grep -oEi 'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)"
fi
done
```

If I pass "select * from table", It is executing elif part only. Even If I pass any query It is executing elif part. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you passing arguments to this script? You seem to be `tail`-ing from a file to read lines

Comment: @TejuPriya: Just a side note: The `.*` in the first *grep*  pattern is redundant.

Comment: @TejuPriya: In the script you are posting, even the *elif* part can not be executed. You are writing `tail -n 0`, which means *take the last zero lines from the log file*, i.e. nothing is piped into the loop and the first *read* fails already. If you really observe the behaviour that the *elif* part is executed, it can't be from this script. BTW, combining the `-n` and `-F` option doesn't make sense.

Comment: @TeuPriya please show us samples of inputs and outputs in your posts it will be better for us to understand the requirements.

Comment: Shouldn't the first *select* be in uppercase?

Comment: just test on my RH and not problem with select. Add `PS4='line $LINENO: ';set -vx` as first line to see what is catched by the `read` on your system.

Comment: Okay I will do that. I am reading in realtime. whenever the new logs is coming I am doing the grep and writing the result

Comment: okay let me try it

Comment: Not working. It is showing elif part only

Comment: @cdarke it is entering to the file.May be I am doing wrong with tail command. I need to capture the log realtime.

Comment: @cdarke okay but the problem is it is running elif part

Comment: Are you sure you are not picking-up the `QueryResult` from the previous iteration of the loop?  If neither `grep`s match then it will display the `$QueryResult` from the previous iteration making you think it is following a different path through the code.  Run it with `set -x` as suggested.

Comment: tee the input to a temporary file just to see if the real input is not in other format that only "look" good but is read by  grep as other thing. then test on this with a direct grep if it can catch your "select"

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I tried with normal grep. Its fetching the result. It is not working in the if else part

Comment: which shell and os are you running on ?

Comment: Ubuntu and linux bash

Comment: could you try  `$(...)` instead of backstick so `$(echo "$LINE" | grep -c "select .*" )` (and same for elif)

Comment: Can you `echo "${line}"` before the first if-statement and use `grep -Eic` ?

Comment: You might want to make those greps case insensitive (i.e. grep -ic ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks very much like you need to discover the `case` statement.

```
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log |  # No backslash necessary here
tr A-Z a-z |  # Convert to lower case
while read -r line    # -r option; lowercase variable
do
    case $line in
      *'select '*)
          AuditTypeID=15
          QueryResult="$(grep -oEi 'SELECT .*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)";;
       *create*)
          AuditTypeID=13
          QueryResult="$(grep -oEi 'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)";;
done
```

The antipattern `if [ $(echo "blah" | grep -c something) -gt 0 ]` is common but very unidiomatic (see [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)); the way to check if `grep` matched something is just `if echo "blah" | grep -q something` but here, you can obviously use the shell's built-in pattern-matching facilities to simplify even further.

Uppercase variable names are reserved for system use; I recommend lower or mixed case for all your script's private variables.

Your code might still have other bugs (rereading the entire file to find the latest `create` or `select` statement very much looks like something you should probably refactor)  but the immediate problem seems to be that you are matching a lowercase string against an uppercase pattern. The code above folds the input to lower case, which is an easy fix as such, but not always a desirable workaround (perhaps you want to see the original line, not the case-folded version, in the output?). Bash 4.x provides a simple facility for case-folding so you could say `case ${line,,}` and remove the `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

with my simulation, that works with:

```
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log | \
while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ select[[:blank:]]count ]]; then
        echo "action select count"
    elif [[ "$line" =~ select[[:blank:]]\*[[:blank:]]from ]]; then
        echo "action select * from"
    elif [[ "$line" =~ DROP ]]; then
        echo "action drop"
    elif [[ "$line" =~ CREATE ]]; then
        echo "action create"
    fi
done
```

- as said **tripleee**:

  - `tail -n 0 -f` starts reading the file without seeking back
  - `tail -n 1 -f` seeks back and prints the last line
- if you test with an echo, ensure to quote, example:
  `echo "select * from table" >> hive-server2.log`

Comment: HI when I test with echo it is working fine. But while copying the output for next next iterations,it is not working.

Comment: ok, but I do not underdstand, it works regardless the number of tests 
echo is a treatment, it is not related to loops?
maybe you could be more clear about: " But while copying the output for next next iterations"

Comment: `tail -n 0 -f` starts reading the file without seeking back. `tail -n 1` seeks back and prints the last line.